# pandas dataframe: extract data with specific crtieria/conditions minimum in a column fixing other columns

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, seaborn, pivot-table, heatmap

First of all many thanks for your help.
I have a table that I import with pandas as df. For each unique foo&bar I want to obtain a new df with the minimum of zoo and the corresponding qux. I tried to simplify my dataframe, but in reality I have some hundreds of qux and foo and some dozens of bar.

my input table :

| foo | bar | zoo | qux |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | HB1 | 9.75 | lab1 |
| aaa | HB1 | 4.87 | lab2 |
| aaa | HB1 | 3.05 | lab3 |
| aaa | TS3 | 8.51 | lab1 |
| aaa | TS3 | 2.58 | lab2 |
| aaa | TS3 | 2.48 | lab3 |
| bbb | HB1 | 9.03 | lab1 |
| bbb | HB1 | 6.11 | lab2 |
| bbb | HB1 | 7.66 | lab3 |
| bbb | TS3 | 3.57 | lab1 |
| bbb | TS3 | 4.25 | lab2 |
| bbb | TS3 | 1.63 | lab3 |

my expected result

| foo | bar | zoo | qux |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | HB1 | 3.05 | lab3 |
| aaa | TS3 | 2.48 | lab3 |
| bbb | HB1 | 6.11 | lab2 |
| bbb | TS3 | 1.63 | lab3 |

I tried to use groupby or pivot_table, I obtained the min zoo for each bar and each foo but I didn't obtain the corresponding qux and the df was completely reshaped and didn't look like my first format. I'm litle bit lost.

Many Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Try this:　`df[df['zoo'].isin(df.groupby(['foo','bar'])['zoo'].min().values)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the index positions of the minimum via groupby, and index the original df to get the rows:

```py
df.loc[df.groupby(['foo', 'bar']).zoo.idxmin()]
 
    foo  bar   zoo   qux
2   aaa  HB1  3.05  lab3
5   aaa  TS3  2.48  lab3
7   bbb  HB1  6.11  lab2
11  bbb  TS3  1.63  lab3
```

Comment: Great...!!!  thanks a lot. I ignored idxmin(). Well, I've learned something new today. Thanks Sammywemmy!

Answer (score 2):

You can sort the values in your dataframe in `descending` order and use `groupby.tail(1)`:

```
df.sort_values(by=['foo','bar','zoo','qux'],ascending=False).groupby(['foo','bar']).tail(1)

    foo  bar   zoo   qux
2   aaa  HB1  3.05  lab3
5   aaa  TS3  2.48  lab3
8   bbb  HB1  7.66  lab3
11  bbb  TS3  1.63  lab3
```

Comment: Great..!  nice  solution, thank so much sophocles !